# Exporting to pdf or svg a 3DPlot changes the color function

Tags: plotting, export, color

I generated a 3D plot with some shades for the z coordinate in Mathematica 11.0. The result is :
[image: graph in jpg format]

However, when I export it as svg or as pdf I get a picture in shades of green only. Moreover, it is clear that neither the pdf nor the svg graphs are vectorial. I use the following commands:

```
Export["KGraph.pdf", KGraph, "PDF"]
Export["KGraph.svg", KGraph, "SVG"]
```

The result is similar to this:
[image]

The code to generate the plot is:

```
KGraph = Plot3D[K1[t, q], {t, 0, 10}, {q, 684123, 750000}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 12],
  AxesLabel -> {"t", "q", "K(t,q)         "}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[.65 (1 - z)]]]
```

How can I ensure that the exported graphic is (a) in vectorial format, (b) uses the right colors?

Comment: Your code does not specify the definition of `K1`, but that is not important because the problem probably pertains regardless of what `K1` is. Next time please try to give a [minimal working example](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2126/what-do-we-mean-by-a-self-contained-minimal-working-example).

Comment: Also, I cannot reproduce your problem on Mathematica 11 running on a Mac.

Comment: Try with any function which has two variables. The MWE working example you mention would not require that I specify a function at all. I add that in the previous version of Mathematica I had (Mathematica 9.0) all the exported images in pdf or svg were in scalar form.

Comment: I reproduced the same problem on another computer under Win7 x64 with Mathematica 11.0.0, except that this time the color was all yellow. When I try shades of Grey, I get a completely black graph.

Comment: A 2D graph is correctly exported in scalar form. Why can't a 3D one?